# When backup programs do not detect newer hard drives, it is because the driver for those hard drives has not been released?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-11

I recently purchased a new laptop and want to back up its C drive. In the past, I've been using a boot USB created by Acronis True Image. However, this time the Acronis program on the USB does not detect the laptop's hard drive. (I've also tried boot USB created by AOMEI Backupper, but the program booted on the USB usually says "True Image has not found any hard disk drive")

I remember encountering a similar problem when I wanted the backup my previous laptop. Back then, I was using an older version of Acronis on the USB. The Acronis program on the USB did not detect the hard drive on my previous laptop. I then proceeded to update the Acronis program on my USB to a newer version. After the update, my Acronis program on the USB was able to pick up the hard drive on my previous laptop.

Since my new laptop was built in December of 2021, is it possible that the driver for that hard drive has not been released to backup software like Acronis or AOMEI? So if I want my backup program on the USB to detect my hard drive, I'll have to wait for the driver to be included in the USB?

Comment: What is a "boot USB"? Please use specific technical terms!

Comment: I remember that some disc imaging software exclude certain discs/partitions from backup that are more common to server systems (like dynamic partitions on Windows). What disk/partition are you talking about?

Comment: "Acronis program on the USB does not detect the laptop's hard drive." - Make sure you boot the system in the correct mode.  If Windows was installed in Legacy Mode then Acronis must also be installed in Legacy Mode.  Likewise, if Windows was installed in UEFI Mode, then Acronis must also be boot with UEFI Mode enabled. *Has for the drivers being supported, SATA and NVMe drivers, are pretty much universal.*

Answer (score 0):

The reason is usually that these USB-bootable recovery systems are Linux based and creating working Linux drivers for new hardware takes some time as the manufacturer don't provide them so the community have to develop the driver based on reverse-engineering. Afterwards the recovery environment has to be updated by the vendor to incorporate those changes (new kernel).

Good Windows backup software allows you to create WinRE based USB boot environment for backup/restore (WinRE is the same platform Windows uses for it's own installer). And in the process of creating these media they allow to integrate the Windows drivers present in the current Windows system. See for example [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree).

Comment: do you have any support for your assertions about Linux drivers? It seems suspect to me as SATA is a well defined standard which has been supported for ages - and in 20 years ive never come across a disk Linux could not recognise. (I expect if we were talking about a raid controller you might be somewhat correct, but this is a laptop)

Comment: Also, Acronis Trueinage very much apprars NOT to be Linux based - https://kb.acronis.com/content/62562 - Similarly for aomei https://www.aomeitech.com/forum/discussion/845/backup-drive-with-linux-os

Comment: @davidgo If you encounter driver problems often depends what distribution you use and how it's kernel update strategy is. I remember cases where SATA HDDs or DVD drives could not be found because they were connected to a third party SATA chipset (not the CPU chipset). Also Ethernet drivers and worst Wifi drivers are often missing.

Comment: @davidgo The link you have posted on Acronis is on the main program. Back in the time when I was using Acronis the main program was Windows (now they seem to have versions for other OS) but the bootable recovery media was Linux based. Not sure if this is still the case. And the link regarding Aomei only speaks about the file-system not the OS the bootable recovery OS uses.

Comment: @davidgo - I have used Acronis for 10 years.  There are two versions of their environment.  One is Linux based the other is based on WinPE. This very well could be a driver issue, but I don't believe it to be one, I suspect an issue related to Legacy/UEFI Mode

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't be related. Have you tried to write to Acronis support? Maybe it's just a bug, or you can adjust some settings.

Alternatively, you can check the compatibility list if there is such provided by your backup program.